# Wordpress: Dynamically display related posts based on custom taxonomy term?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I need to add **related posts** to my custom post type (using current taxonomy term). I know how to display them, I just need to be able to retrieve the currently selected taxonomy terms.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'mycustomposttype',
    'posts_per_page'    => 3,
    'orderby'           => 'rand',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'thetaxonomy',
            'terms'     => 'theterm',
            'field'     => 'slug',
        )
    ),
);
```

I need to dynamically populate "**thetaxonomy**" and "**theterm**" based on what's currently selected on the page. Getting the term is easy enough, but I'm struggling to get "**thetaxonomy**" slug.

Thanks in advance!

**FIGURED IT OUT!**

In case anyone is looking to accomplish the same thing

```
$currentTax = get_the_taxonomies($post->ID);
foreach($currentTax as $slug => $tax) {
    $currentSlug = $slug;
};
$theTerms = array();
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, $currentSlug, array("fields" => "all"));
foreach($term_list as $term_single) {
    array_push($theTerms, $term_single->slug);
}
```

So the query would look like this...

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'mycustomposttype',
    'posts_per_page'    => 3,
    'orderby'           => 'rand',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => $slug,
            'terms'     => $theTerms,
            'field'     => 'slug',
        )
    ),
);
```